# How are your Studies going?

Tags: grammar, british-english, spoken-english

Confused between 
1) How are your Studies going ?
2) How is your Study going ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some overlap, but generally speaking:

**How are your studies going?** is asking about your studies in general, not necessarily limited to one subject area (although it may be limited by context), and probably not limited to one period of study.

**How is your study going?** is asking about a particular period of study.  For example, if you know that someone is meant to be studying English on a particular day, you are asking about how their study is going *now* rather than *in general*.

A **study** can also be a particular research project, so **How is your study going?** could be asking about that.

Sometimes **How is your study going?** or **How is your homework going?** or **How is your revision going?** is a rhetorical reminder to a student that they are supposed to be studying that evening - whereas **How are your studies going?** is usually either a genuine enquiry or just a polite conversation-filler.